# iFrameResizer not calculating height of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I have an external domain 'domainB' that I am pulling content from. Included in domainB's scripts is iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js

My domain 'domainA' includes iframeResizer.min.js and I am calling it like:

```
$('iframe').iFrameResize({log:true, checkOrigin:false,
heightCalculationMethod:"taggedElement"});
```

No matter what I change the 'heightCalculationMethod' to, it doesn't have any affect on the iframe's height. Below is the logging

> [iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] Added missing iframe ID: iFrameResizer0 (http://domainB/)
>   iframeResizer.min.js:8 
>   [iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] IFrame scrolling disabled for iFrameResizer0
>   iframeResizer.min.js:8 
>   
> [iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] [init] Sending msg to iframe[iFrameResizer0] (iFrameResizer0:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:taggedElement:null:null:0:false:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *
>   iframeResizer.min.js:8 
>   
> [iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] [iFrame.onload] Sending msg to iframe[iFrameResizer0] (iFrameResizer0:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:taggedElement:null:null:0:false:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *

So it appears it is working, there are no errors, but it is having no effect. Is there a better way to do this, one that would actually change the height of the iframe?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. In my case this was because in the page within the frame (the page with iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js) there is an external plugin which sets this CSS style:

```
body,html{height:100%}
```

I fixed it by adding this CSS in the page within the frame:

```
 body, html {height:inherit !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue as you (same settings and all), and realized that I did not have `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js` included correctly on my 'domaindB'

Once I made sure it was included, it worked - and a much longer list of logs was being printed.

Like you, I was under the assumption that because the initial short list of logs (that you quoted) were being printed, the two pages were communicating; however, this is not true.

If you have sourceMaps enabled, you should see logs coming from `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js`

like this:

`iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:150[iFrameSizer][iFrameResizer0] Initialising iFrame (http://domainB.site)
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:150[iFrameSizer][iFrameResizer0] TargetOrigin for parent set to: *
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:150[iFrameSizer][iFrameResizer0] height calculation method set to "taggedElement"`

etc etc.

Comment: Thanks, this precisely solved my issue. What @sweatherall notes is found here: [https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer-react#usage](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer-react#usage)


> The page in the iframe then needs (iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js) from iframe-resizer. This file is designed to be a guest on someone else's system, so has no dependencies and won't do anything until it's activated by a message from the containing page.

Answer (score 1):

If that is all you are seeing in the log, then the script isn't being loaded into domain B, or some other JS code on domain B is crashing and stopping this JS from running.